# Django - show sums of a table of records

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a table which has a list of invoices and their details:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    invoiceNum = models.CharField(etc...)
    invoiceDate = models.DateField(etc...)
    customerID = models.ForeignKey(etc...)
    isPaid = models.CharField(etc...)
```

The `Invoice` records do not hold the actual invoice total. Instead, an invoice's total is made up of several `Invoice_Line_Item` records, held in another table:

```
class Invoice_Line_Item(models.Model):
    invNum = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
    itemName = models.CharField(etc...)
    itemPrice = models.DecimalField(etc...)
```

I have a webapp that shows all the invoices in a big HTML table, along with all the details of that invoice on the table's `tr` row. Details such as, Invoice Date, Invoice Number, Customer ID, all come from that `Invoice` table. There are hundreds of invoices to display in this `HTML` `table`.

What I would like to do is also show each invoice's total value - which is the sum of all the line items. However, I can't think of a simple way to acomplish this since the invoice details and the line items that make up the invoice's total are in two different tables.

One way I thought is to pass the entire `Invoice_Line_Item` querySet into the HTML template, then for each invoice displayed in a table `tr`, I could iterate over the entire `Invoice_Line_Item` querySet, adding up all the line items that match the current invoice. This, however, seems hugely inefficient.

Any better ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One word: Aggregation

```
Invoice_Line_Item.objects.filter(invNum=invoice).aggregate(Sum('itemPrice'))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Another way is to store the total in Invoice and update it whenever you change a related `Invoice_Line_Item`

Comment: Interesting. So I would created an aggregated querySet, and pass _that_ to the template. That way I would only iterate over an aggregated querySet which is way smaller than the entire `Invoice_Line_Item` querySet. Do I have that right?

Comment: No, the aggregate returns a dictionary like so {'itemPrice__Sum': 100}. I think. You could make it a function of Invoice, which would make it prettier. Read the documentation for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm reading through the documentation now. I think this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

One more word: annotate.

```
from django.models import Sum

Invoice.objects.filter( .. ).annotate( InvTotal=Sum( 'invoice_line_number__itemPrice' ) )
```

InvTolal becomes a new attribute of Invoice object, you can use it in template the same way as invoiceNum or invoiceDate.

With this approach you do not have to pass any additional data structures to your template, only a QuerySet of Invoices.

Please note:
Argument of Sum is a string, which is a concatenation of the name of related model converted to lowercase, than double '_', and than the name of a field in related model.